# Частичная специализация нескольких типов сразу

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс hash

```
template<class>
struct hash;
```

Теперь я начинаю реализовывать частичную специализацию для всех арифметических типов:

```
  template<>
  struct hash<bool> {
      size_t operator()(bool value) const {
        return static_cast<size_t>(value);
      }
  };

  template<>
  struct hash<char> {
      size_t operator()(char value) const {
        return static_cast<size_t>(value);
      }
  };

  template<>
  struct hash<signed char> {
      size_t operator()(signed char value) const {
        return static_cast<size_t>(value);
      }
  };
```

Сразу замечаю, что реализация везде одна и приходит мысль написать что-то такое:

```
  template<Ty>
  struct hash<std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Ty>, Ty>> {
      size_t operator()(Ty value) const {
        return static_cast<size_t>(value);
      }
  };
```

Возможно ли написать частичную специализацию для нескольких типов сразу?

Comment: Только, пожалуйста, не говорите, что такая реализация хэша - плохая задумка :')

Answer (score 3):

В C++20 так:

```
template <typename T> requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
struct hash<T>
{

};
```

В более ранних версиях так:

```
template <typename T, typename = void> // Добавляем лишний шаблонный параметр.
struct hash {};

template <typename T>
struct hash<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
{

};
```